# Select worksheet as string or integer in function

Tags: vba, excel

The below code doesn’t work when I call the `Function opensheet(“mysheet”)`. Can I call the sheet by it’s name or sheet number like this?

```
Function opensheet(tab As String)

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(tab).Select

End Function
```

Comment: If there is no output here, you should just do this as a `Sub`, not a `Function`. Is the goal here only to select a certain sheet?

Comment: Thanks. For simplicity, I posted a portion of a function that’s part of a bigger function, hence the desire for that.

Comment: Best not to simplify too much - post the full code if it's not too long.  Exactly how are you calling this function - from VBA or from a worksheet?

Comment: Why do you need to `.Select` a sheet? You can avoid using `.Select` or `.Selection`. A sheet or cell does not have to be active or selected to be modified/copied/deleted/etc.

Comment: Just being generic and trying to tackle why calling opensheet doesn’t work. How would I structure Worksheets(tab) to meet the objective? Thanks

Comment: You need to define tab. Currently, your command reads as follows `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(nothing).Select` which is not valid. Also, how are you calling your function?

Comment: urdearboy, tab is defined as a string in the function name. hidefguy can you post more of your function so we get a sense of whats going on? are you defining any variables at the top? if you define tab again it will wipe out what is passed in. Also, you are definitely passing in the correct sheet name right?

Comment: Dan. Have the code at home PC, but it defines as follows: Function MyCode ( tab As String, dest As String, divi As String). The dest and divi target cell ranges in Excel which works. The tab part not working for worksheet name target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use tab as a variable name, I modified your code and tested and it works fine:

```
Function opensheet(str_Tab As String)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(str_Tab).Select
End Function

Sub hello()
    opensheet "TestName"
End Sub
```

Try to steer clear of reserved words like tab, sheet, book and the like, I usually either call it MyTab or something like that or I prefix it with the type so str_tab as it's a string or lng_tab if it's a long, it helps a lot when your code starts getting to large sizes.

Hope that helps

EDIT: Here are a couple of cut down ways to get the same result from what you have posted as your final routine:

This code will poll a list of sheet fed into the array on the third line, it's flexible because the sheets can be called anything you like.

```
Function SumCounts(sht As String, dest As String, addr As String, divi As String)
Dim SheetArray As Variant, TempValue As Long, X As Long
SheetArray = Array("BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH", "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "MMM", "NNN", "OOO", "PPP")
TempValue = 0
For X = LBound(SheetArray) To UBound(SheetArray)
    TempValue = TempValue + Application.CountIf(Workbooks(SheetArray(X)).Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0")
Next
Workbooks("MASTER").Sheets("XXX").Range(dest).Value = TempValue / Workbooks("MASTER").Sheets("XXX").Range(divi).Value
End Function
```

This one uses the ASCII codes and assumes your sheets are named one after the other, it's less flexible than using the above code but it's shorter

```
Function SumCounts(sht As String, dest As String, addr As String, divi As String)
Dim TempValue As Long, X As Long
TempValue = 0
For X = 66 To 80
    TempValue = TempValue + Application.CountIf(Workbooks(Chr(X) & Chr(X) & Chr(X)).Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0")
Next
Workbooks("MASTER").Sheets("XXX").Range(dest).Value = TempValue / Workbooks("MASTER").Sheets("XXX").Range(divi).Value
End Function
```

Also I probably wouldn't be doing sheet manipulation in a function, I would be doing the calculation in the function then the manipulation in the sheet, just my thoughts but it makes it super easy to maintain :).

Hope that helps you out in some way.

Comment: Didn’t realize it’s as simple as that. Appreciate the help Dan

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. For future search/info reference here is the full function:

```
Function SumCounts(sht As String, dest As String, addr As String, divi As String)

    Workbooks("MASTER").Sheets("XXX").Range(dest).Value = _
    (Application.CountIf(Workbooks("BBB").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("CCC").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("DDD").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("EEE").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("FFF").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("GGG").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("HHH").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("III").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("JJJ").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("KKK").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("LLL").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("MMM").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("NNN").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("OOO").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0") + _
    Application.CountIf(Workbooks("PPP").Worksheets(sht).Range(addr), ">0")) / _
    Workbooks("MASTER").Sheets("XXX").Range(divi).Value

End Function
```

Comment: Check my edit to my answer for a better way to do this :)

Comment: Dan. I need a small VBA/Excel project coded, involving charts and financial data. Would you consider doing it? If so, please reply with some contact info. Thanks

Comment: Possibly, it would better for me to help you build it and you will learn that way.

Comment: I’m very time constrained, but that would be great if we can do it in bits and pieces. Can we move this into a discussion forum of your choice within a private message portal?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, if you just search me on FB, I use my real name on here and I am the one with a picture of my cat and me together, drop me a line then I can give you my email address and we can collaborate.

Comment: Lol. I don’t FB. I’m a recluse. Just throw it in your profile here and delete it after I drop the email.

Comment: OK My spam email is in my profile, drop me a note and I will remove it again.

Answer (score -1):

Have fun with these functions ..

```
    'To check if a worksheet exists
    Public Function worksheetExists(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sheetNameStr As String) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    worksheetExists = (wb.Worksheets(sheetNameStr).Name <> "")
    Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0

    End Function

    'To get the name of the first visible worksheet in the workbook (the one at the far left)
    Public Function getFirstSheet(ByVal wb As Workbook) As String
    Dim x As Integer, sheetCount As Long

    sheetCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
    For x = 1 To sheetCount
        If wb.Worksheets(x).Visible = xlSheetVisible Then Exit For
    Next x
    getFirstSheet = wb.Worksheets(x).Name

    End Function

    'To activate a specific worksheet and move cursor to a specific position
    Public Sub activateSheet(ByRef wb As Workbook, ByVal sheetNameStr As String, Optional ByVal lngCol As Long = 1, Optional ByVal moveToEndCol As Boolean = False)

    If worksheetExists(wb, sheetNameStr) Then
        With wb.Worksheets(sheetNameStr)
            If .Visible = xlSheetHidden Or .Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then .Visible = xlSheetVisible
            .Activate
            If moveToEndCol Then
                Application.GoTo Reference:=.Range(columnLetter(lngCol) & LastRowInOneColumn(wb.Worksheets(sheetNameStr), 2) + 1), Scroll:=True
            Else
                Application.GoTo Reference:=.Range(columnLetter(lngCol) & 1), Scroll:=True
            End If
            .Activate
        End With
    End If

    End Sub

'To return the column letter for a given column number
Function columnLetter(ByVal lngCol As Long) As String
Dim splitArr As Variant

splitArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
columnLetter = splitArr(0)
Erase splitArr

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks bud. I’ll play with that later if needed

Comment: if it can help you, I will be happy. Can you vote up please it can help you. Many thx.